# (Validation.Errors)[0]

Tags: wpf

What is use of (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent and also tell the significance of [0] in this context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Validation.Errors` is an array and you get the first element in that arrah/list by using "index" 0. To get a certain index in an array, you use `[ ]`.

In this case you basicly say:

Give me the first record of the Validation.Errors

> `Validation.Errors` Gets the
>   collection of all active
>   [ValidationError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationerror.aspx) objects on the bound
>   element.

You could get all validation errors by using the enumerator like this:

`foreach(var error in Validation.Errors){}`

In case an Array is Empty, there wont be any elements at `[0]` thus throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: Thanks For the Reply.Please tell me if Validation.Errors can stores errors at [1] position ? What is the meaning of active ValidationError objects?

Comment: There could be errors at another index than 0, therefore you should use an iterator to go through the collection. `foreach(var error in Validation.Errors){}` using `Valiadtion.Errors.Count` will give you the amount of errors in that error list.